# pass route paramerter in testcase

Tags: phpunit, laravel-5, testcase

I am writing a `testcase` in which i have to send parameter as we pass in route. Here is my controller.

```
   class TestingControll extends Controller {

    public function addTestUsingParameters(Response $response)
    {       
        $firstNum  = $response->firstNum ;
        $secondNum = $response->secondNum ;

        $sumOfNumbers = $firstNum + $secondNum;

        return $sumOfNumbers;
    }
}
```

Here is my route

```
Route::get('test/cal/{firstNum}/{secondNum}', array('as' => 'testCal', 'uses' => 'TestingControll@addTestUsingParameters'));
```

Here is my `Testcase` code.

```
    class CalculatorTest extends TestCase {

    public function testCanAddNumbers()
    {
        $calcu = $this->action('GET','TestingControll@addTestUsingParameters',['firstNum'=>4,'secondNum'=>4]);   
        $this->assertEquals(10,$calcu->getContent());
    }
}
```

I have read the documentation,but i did't get the idea, how to do this.?
Anyone know about this problem?

Comment: Does the route/controller work when you try in your browser?

Comment: What is output/error of code you provided? Why do you inject `Response` in `addTestUsingParameters`? `assertEquals` should check for 8, not 10 :)

Comment: @DanielAntos thanks for pointing out `Response` parameter, its my typo mistake, i should have to pass `Request` parameter.